# Is it illegal to advertise another entity's product?

Tags: united-states, intellectual-property, trademark, advertisements, branding

I'm a retailer of products. One product in particular needs more attention, but the manufacturing company doesn't advertise their products in the media which my customers reside (mainly YouTube). I would like to draw more attention to the product, and create an advertisement featuring the product, but spin it as "you can buy this at my website".

Is it illegal to feature another entity's product in my advertisement, given that:

- They do not have a trademark
- They do not have any patents on the product
- They do have a brand name
- The entity is headquartered in the UK and I am in the US

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No it’s not illegal

It’s called retailing:

- https://youtu.be/ywSkKkuGQ2A
- https://youtu.be/k8OreiHU91Y
- https://youtu.be/XpR6y1sNArU

You are allowed to advertise the products you sell. Even if you don’t make them. You can even use their trademarks to identify them - that’s what trademarks are for.